# Why do 4 days in the output of datetime() correspond to 1 month and 4 days with datestr() in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, date

I am running into the following problem in Matlab 2019a.

```
>> datestr(datetime('20190927','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd')-datetime('20190923','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd'),'yyyymmdd')
ans =
    '00000104'
```

Why is the answer 1 month 4 days? Shouldn't it be zero month 4 days?

EDIT:

I realize that arithmetic on datetime arrays create duration arrays. But I don't know how to set format of duration arrays after doing arithmetic on datetime arrays or how to retrieve the duration data in a format free way.

Datetime arithmetic is what I need. So I am asking the question so I *can* do datetime arithmetic without issue.

Comment: @O'Neil: They stand for different things in either function.

Comment: That's one of the most effed up things I've read in the MATLAB documentation. I noticed this `mm`/`MM` difference too, it turns out it's intentional. Incredible!

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thanks for joining in. I don't understand fully. If 0000 year 01 month 04 day represent 4th of Jan, why is the year zeroed at 0000? Is that the default zeroth year in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```matlab
d = datetime('20190927','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd')-datetime('20190923','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd')
```

returns:

```
d = 
  duration
   96:00:00
```

That is, 96 hours. Converting this to a date string results in January 4th. If you start counting hours from midnight on the year 0, 96 hours later you end up on January 4th. There's no 0th month.

What you can do is this:

```matlab
d = duration(d,'Format','dd:hh:mm:ss')
```

which returns:

```
d = 
  duration
   04:00:00:00
```

You can also do:

```matlab
d = days(d)
```

which returns:

```
d =
     4
```